# Product Feed successfully submitted but in amazon dashboard it could not display

Tags: amazon-mws

In amazon feed submission i am trying to submit product data feed on amazon mws.

Below is my xml feed code. Everything is working fine this feed also submitted successfully. But in amazon seller dashboard it is not displaying.

is there any different format of xml from my above product format? Anybody have proper multiple feed upload sample format? Threw in amazon product list the product can display. Provide product xml feed sample code if available.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"> 
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.1</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
        <SKU>1234</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>UPC</Type>
            <Value>1234123412343</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <Condition>
        <ConditionType>Refurbished</ConditionType>
        <ConditionNote>Looks like new</ConditionNote>
        </Condition>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title>First march Product feed</Title>
            <Brand>blabla</Brand>
            <Description>my desc</Description>
            <BulletPoint>f1</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>f2</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>f3</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>f4</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>f5</BulletPoint>
            <PackageWeight unitOfMeasure="GR">290</PackageWeight>
            <ShippingWeight unitOfMeasure="GR">5</ShippingWeight>
            <Manufacturer>A manufacturer</Manufacturer>
            <MfrPartNumber>1234123412343</MfrPartNumber>
            <SearchTerms>a</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>b</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>c</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>d</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>e</SearchTerms>
            <RecommendedBrowseNode>111111</RecommendedBrowseNode>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <CE>
                <ProductType>
                    <PhoneAccessory/>
                </ProductType>
            </CE>
        </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
        <SKU>3333</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>UPC</Type>
            <Value>4444123412343</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
        </Condition>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title>First march Product feed second</Title>
            <Brand>brand</Brand>
            <Description>my desc 2</Description>
            <MfrPartNumber>4444123412343</MfrPartNumber>
            <RecommendedBrowseNode>111111</RecommendedBrowseNode>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <Sports>
                <ProductType>SportingGoods</ProductType>
            </Sports>
        </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

I have created exact format of Multiple Product feed upload using xml. below is my code which is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.1</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MARKETPLACE_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>xxxxxxx</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>UPC</Type>
                <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>First Try Multiple Title Product one</Title>
                <Brand>Example Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>external-cell-phone-battery-packs</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                            <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>xxxx</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>UPC</Type>
                <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Second try Multi Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>external-cell-phone-battery-packs</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                            <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>xxxxxx</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>UPC</Type>
                <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Third Try Multi Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>external-cell-phone-battery-packs</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                            <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Its Working. :) :)